# How can I enable or disable inheritance from a template using another template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

I want to enable a template to include functionality via CRTP and also use the same template without this functionality e.g. for classes that do not include a function requiered by the CRTP template.

The following code using [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) works:

```
#include <type_traits>

class NOCRTP{/*empty dummy class*/};
template <class T> class CRTP{/*addditional functionality here*/};

template<typename T, bool CRTP_ENABLED = true>
class Ok: public std::conditional<CRTP_ENABLED, CRTP<Ok<T> >, NOCRTP >::type{
};
```

The way without std::conditional via an additional template parameter does not since TYPE depends on itself.

```
template< typename T, typename TYPE> class Fail;
template< typename T, typename TYPE = CRTP< Fail<T,TYPE > > >
class Fail: public TYPE{
};
```

Can this be solved by some kind of forward declaration or is the std::conditional solution the only way ?

Comment: May I ask what this is for? What is the use-case? Is it just for curiosity, or is there some actual problem you want to solve this way? I ask because having different base-classes in different situations will be a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: ;-) A little bit of both. I use a mixin to introduce time as a property for various types. Additionally I wanted to reenable basic arithmetic for types where it makes sense. Think of Timed<Vector3d> with Vector3d supporting non member operator+. Timed<Vector3d> does not, but using the above I could take a Barton Nackman approach to reenable it generically where operator+ makes any sense. E.g. not necessarily for sth. like Timed<Line>